# How to write Pandas data frame to Excel file on FTP directly

Tags: python, pandas, ftp

I want to create an Excel file on FTP directly from Pandas data frame. I've tried this code, but I receive an "invalid extension/corrupt file" error from Excel:

```
from ftplib import *
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas
import io

ftp = FTP('ftp.mysite.com')
ftp.login('un', 'pw')
ftp.cwd('/')
buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
your_pandas_df.to_excel(buffer)
text = buffer.getvalue()
bio = io.BytesIO(str.encode(text))

ftp.storbinary('STOR filename.xlsx', bio)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Excel file is a binary file. You should never try to use a `StringIO` object but directly use a `BytesIO` one. Also, there's no need to make yet another copy of the file using `getvalue`, just `seek` the buffer to the beginning before the upload:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
your_pandas_df.to_excel(buffer)
buffer.seek(0)

ftp.storbinary('STOR filename.xlsx', buffer)
```